# What does public<T> void run (T object ) { } means?

Tags: java, generics

I am reading generics and tried writing the below code. There are no compilation error.

```
import java.util.*;

public class JavaApplication14 {

    public<T>  void run (T obj ) {
        //Do Something
    }

  public static void main(String[] args) {     
      JavaApplication14  m= new JavaApplication14();
      m.run(new ArrayList<>());  
      m.run(new Interger(5);
      m.run(5);
     }
}
```

If the function is

```
 public<T extends Number>  void run (T obj) {
            //Do Something
        }
```

It makes sense as we can restrict the arguments of this function to a Number and its subtypes. But am terribly confused what the function 'run' without any bound mean?
Can it now take any object as the argument ? In what scenario do i need to use such a function with generics ?

Comment: Per definition there cannot be any subtypes to Integer, since Integer is actually final ;-)

Comment: @oops.missed it.Apologies for such a silly mistake.Editing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Part of your confusion may stem from the fact that there is no point in having `run` be a generic method in this case. You normally use a type parameter to create a relationship between two parameter types and/or between parameter type and return type. In your example `run` could just as well have been declared as requiring an `Object` parameter (a type parameter without a declared bound effectively has `Object` as its bound).

There is one case I know of where you might usefully use a type parameter in a single parameter type: when you want to be able to manipulate a collection in a way that doesn't depend on the element type, but which does require inserting elements into the collection. Consider for example a hypothetical "reverse list" method:

```
<T> void reverse(List<T> list)
{
    List<T> reversed = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (int i = list.size(); i > 0; i--) {
        reversed.add(list.get(i - 1));
    }
    list.clear();
    list.addAll(reversed);
}
```

It would be difficult to write this in a way that didn't require a type parameter, i.e. that takes a `List<?>` parameter. The only way to do it without casts is to do:

```
void reverse2(List<?> list)
{
    reverse(list);  // call reverse as defined above!
}
```

But again, this doesn't apply in the example you discuss.

So in summary:

A type parameter without an explicit bound effectively has an `Object` bound.

There are two reasons why a method might need a type parameter (either with or without an explicit bound):

- Specify a relationship between parameter types and/or return type
- Capture a potential wildcard as a type parameter to allow operations that wouldn't otherwise be possible (as in the `reverse` example).

The example method you discussed:

```
public<T>  void run (T obj )
```

... does neither of these, and so the type parameter is pointless. The method might just as well have been declared as `public void run(Object obj)`.

Answer (score 3):

**It allows you to avoid any cast.**

```
public class SomeClass {
      void doStuff();    
}

public<T extends SomeClass>  void run (T obj) {
    //can call doStuff without any casting
    obj.doStuff();
}

public<T>  void run (T) {
    //Here, there's no clue to perform the implicit cast.
    obj.doStuff();  //won't compile
}
```

Comment: So does `public void run (SomeClass obj)` (or `Object obj` in the case he asks about).`

Comment: What about this possible signature `public<T extends SomeClass>  void run (List<T> obj)`. You would be able to pass a `List<SubClassOfSomeClass>`, while not allowing `List<Integer>`  for example. Be aware that `List< SubClassOfSomeClass>` does not inherit from `List< SomeClass>`even if those T types are IS-A. Thus this would not work with `public<T>  void run (List<T> obj)`.

Comment: I am quite aware of that. Note that the author said he already understands what a generic method with bounds could be useful for, and asked why would you have a method _without_ bounds.

Comment: Well, indeed ;) Davmac's answer gives a good example so, still with...list ;)

Answer (score 1):

While in this case the function could take `Object` just as well, the variant that makes sense to you is equivalent to `public void run(Number obj) { ... }` as well. For an example where lack of bound makes sense consider a case where the return type mentions `T`: `public <T> List<T> singletonList(T obj)`.

Answer (score 1):

### Some theory

There're generic methods. Their main goal is generic algorithms (receive and return same types).

**Code that uses generics has many benefits over non-generic code:**

- Elimination of casts.
- Stronger type checks at compile time.
- Enabling programmers to implement generic algorithms.

### A little practice

Consider the following code:

```
class MyClass {

    public void method() {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        runFirst(new MyClass());
        runSecond(new MyClass());
    }

    public static <T extends MyClass> void runFirst(T obj) {
        obj.method();
    }

    public static <T> void runSecond(T obj) {
        ((MyClass) obj).method();
    }
}
```

The `runFirst()` method allows us to avoid cast to class and all its subclasses. In `runSecond()` method we can get any type of parameter (`<T>`, roughly speaking, means `<T extends Object>`). Firstly, we must cast to `MyClass` and then call its method.

Comment: I think you've either not read or misunderstood the question. This is a general answer about generic methods as opposed to a specific answer to the specific question.

Comment: @davmac, I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

First of all I will start with the meaning of `public <T> void run(T object) { ... }`. Yes when you use that kind of code you than you may use any object as a parameter of run. If you want to restrict the arguments of this function to a specific interface, class or its sub classes you can just write code like `NotGenericRun` which is shown below.

```
public class NotGenericRun {

    public void run(ArrayList<?> list) {
        String message = "Non Generic Run List: ";
        System.out.println(message.concat(list.toString()));
    }

    public void run(int intValue) {
        String message = "Non Generic Run Int: ";
        System.out.println(message.concat(String.valueOf(intValue)));
    }

}
```

Here I tested output of `GenericRun` and `NotGenericRun` classes.

```
public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericRun m = new GenericRun();
        m.run(new ArrayList<>());
        m.run(new Integer(5));
        m.run(5);

        NotGenericRun n = new NotGenericRun();
        n.run(new ArrayList<>());
        n.run(new Integer(5));
        n.run(13);
    }

}
```

Output of this code was following:

```
Generic Run: []
Generic Run: 5
Generic Run: 5
Non Generic Run List: []
Non Generic Run Int: 5
Non Generic Run Int: 13
```

When you use Generic run as I already said arguments may be any object but there is other way of restricting the arguments while still using generics.

```
public class GenericRun {

    public <T> void run(T object) {
        String message = "Generic Run: ";
        System.out.println(message.concat(object.toString()));
    }

}
```

This is how.

```
public class GenericRun <T> {

    public void run(T object) {
        String message = "Generic Run: ";
        System.out.println(message.concat(object.toString()));
    }

}
```

In this case you'll be using `GenericClass` like this:

```
GenericRun<Integer> m = new GenericRun<Integer>();
m.run(new Integer(5));
m.run(5);
```

and only value that it will be tacking should be stated while creating class. I can't think of scenario when `public <T> void run(T object) { ... }` may be needed but it might occur when you'll need the method to get every argument or you don't know what arguments will be (but it's really less likely). I think more often when you'll be using generics with run like this:

```
public class GenericRun <T> {

    public void run(T object) {
        ...
    }

}
```

**I was searching about usage of generic methods [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) you can read more about why may we need generic methods.**

Here is another example:

```
public class GenericRun {

    public <T> void run(T[] inputArray) {
        for (T element : inputArray) {
            System.out.printf("%s ", element);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Using this class you can print array of different type using a single Generic method:

```
public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericRun m = new GenericRun();
        // Create arrays of Integer, Double and Character
        Integer[] intArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        Double[] doubleArray = { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4 };
        Character[] charArray = { 'H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O' };

        System.out.println("Array integerArray contains:");
        m.run(intArray); // pass an Integer array

        System.out.println("\nArray doubleArray contains:");
        m.run(doubleArray); // pass a Double array

        System.out.println("\nArray characterArray contains:");
        m.run(charArray); // pass a Character array
    }

}
```

I hope I answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing makes sense here is if this was some kind of pseudo-abstract or base class, that provided framework for behaviour and let another coders implement their own logic, but also provided default null action.

It could allow for better generic type-setting, for example as:

```
class MySubClass extends JavaApplication14 {
    public <T> void run(T obj){
        new ArrayList<T>().add(obj);
    }
}
```